# Best way to give site sub-page it's own domain?

Tags: urls, child-pages, domain

I am trying to figure out the best way to have a sub-page of an existing site as the landing page of another domain.

Here is the scenario: I have a wordpress site (examplesite.co.uk) that uses a translator plugin. The plugin uses cached pages for translations that cannot be indexed by search engines. I wish to make separate landing pages that will use examplesite.fr, examplesite.es, examplesite.it, etc. that will contain text written in these languages so that they can be indexed by search engines and hopefully receive more organic traffic from these counties. I am hoping that I can make these separate pages a part of examplesite.co.uk utilizing the theme, js scripts, etc. but still give them a separate domain. The landing pages will link into the main site as well, to posts, products, etc.

The site is currently hosted on a shared server, and uses cpanel as the main admin tool. I can use Subdomains, Addon Domains, Parked Domains and Redirects. With my limited knowledge I imagine that I should use Addon domains to achieve what I am after. Is this correct? Which is the best way to do this? Will it mean that there could be confusion for search engines and indexing?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

1. Point your add-on domains to Wordpress root
2. Create Wordpress landing pages
3. Point to landing page using add-on domain
4. Rel=canonical will prevent duplicate indexing penalty
5. All landing page links will automatically point to canonical domain
6. Naturally you will do all your editing from the canonical domain
7. If you run into trouble check your .htaccess file for redirects

Comment: Thanks Scriptonomy, that is very helpful. I thought I was on the right track but needed an experienced user to point out the procedure and pit-falls.